# On scrolling down a space can be seen above my sidebar

Tags: html, css, sticky

Open the sidebar by clicking on left of Hakuna-Mipaka and just scroll down you will get the problem.
Whenever I open my sidebar and scrolls down then a space can be seen over my sidebar, i want my sidebar to be stick to the navbar even after I scroll it down.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#f2f2f2;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav{
     background: #222222;
     padding:10px 40px 10px 70px;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     border-left: none;
     border-right: none;
     
     width: 100%;
}

.nav ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav ul li.logo{
    flex:1;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav ul div.items{
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.nav ul div.items a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18 px;
    padding:0 12px;
}

.nav ul div.items a:hover{
    color:cyan
}

.searchicon{
    height:40px;
    width:240px;
    display:flex;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.searchicon input{
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    border:none;
    padding:0 10px;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.searchicon .icon{
    height:100%;
    width:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1 px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.searchicon .icon:hover{
    background: red;
}

.searchicon .icon span{
    color:#222222;
    font-size: 18px;

}

.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left:-300px;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background:#042331;
    transition:all .5s ease;
}

.sidebar header{
    font-size:22px;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    background:#063146;
    user-select: none;
}

.sidebar ul a{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    line-height:65px;
    font-size:20px ;
    color:white;
    padding-left: 33px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition:0.4s;
}


ul li:hover a{
    padding-left: 43px;

}

.sidebar ul a i{
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.sidebar ul .setting-btn.show{
    display:block;
}

.sidebar span{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    font-size:25px;
    margin-top:18px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#check{
    display:none;
}

label #btn, label #cancel{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#042331;
    border-radius:3px;
}

label #btn{
    left:10px;
    top:9px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color:white;
    padding:6px 12px;
    transition:all .5s;
}

label #cancel{
    z-index:1111;
    left:-195px;
    top:78px;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#0a5275;
    padding:4px 9px;
    transition:all .5s ease;
}

#check:checked ~ .sidebar{
    left:0;
    position: fixed;

}

#check:checked ~ label #btn{
    left:250px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;

}

#check:checked ~ label #cancel{
    left:250px;
    

}

.parent-container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.container1{
    
    width:75%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #e3e4e6;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container1-items{
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px;
    font-size:25px;
    
}

.container1 .container1-items a{
    color:slategray;
    padding:5px;
}

.container1 .container1-items i{
    color:slategray;
}

.container2{
    
    width:75%;
    height:220px;
    margin:20px;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #FFF;
    
}

.container2-items{
    width:28%;
    height:60px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right: 34px;
    font-size:25px;
    border:1px solid black;
    color:black;
    
    
}

.container3{
    
    width:75%;
    height:450px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container3-header{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    padding:10px;
    display:flex;
}

.container3-header-link{
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#1BBAE1;
    
}



.container3-item1{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:48%;
    height:450px;
    margin-right:40px;
}

.container3-item2{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:48%;
    height:450px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.container3-item2-1{
    width:100%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
.container3-item2-1-1{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
}
.container3-item2-2{
    width:100%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
.container3-item2-2-1{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="logo">Hakuna-Mipaka</li>
            <div class="items">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <li class="searchicon">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
                <label class="icon">
                    <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                </label>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>

    </label>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <header>My Profile</header>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hamburger"></i>My Shop<span class="fas fa-angle-right"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="setting-btn"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Settings & privacy<span
                        class="fas fa-angle-right first"></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>Help & support<span
                        class="fas fa-angle-right"></span></a> </li>


            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment-alt"></i>Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hotel"></i>name</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>Address</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt"></i>Phone_number</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-building"></i>City</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-fax"></i>Pincode</a></div>

        </div>

        <div class="container2">
            <div class="container2-items">1</div>
            <div class="container2-items">2</div>
            <div class="container2-items">3</div>
            <div class="container2-items">4</div>
            <div class="container2-items">5</div>

        </div>

        <div class="container3">
            <div class="container3-item1">
                <div class="container3-header">
                    Your <strong>Events</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container3-item2">
                <div class="container3-item2-1">
                    <div class="container3-item2-1-1">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container3-item2-2">
                    <div class="container3-item2-2-1">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Open the sidebar by clicking on left of Hakuna-Mipaka and just scroll down you will get the problem.
Whenever I open my sidebar and scrolls down then a space can be seen over my sidebar, i want my sidebar to be stick to the navbar even after I scroll it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening the menu, the "Hakuna-Mipaka" caption is not obscured by the sidebar box. Everything I changed I marked in the css code.

```js
/*$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var height_nav = $(".nav").height();
    if (top >= height_nav+22) {
      $(".sidebar").css('top', 0);
    } else {
      $(".sidebar").css('top', height_nav-top+22);
    }  
       
 });*/
 
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    let top = window.pageYOffset;
    let height_nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0].scrollHeight;
    let sidebar_top = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0];

    if (top >= (height_nav - 2)) {
      sidebar_top.style.top = 0 + 'px' ;
    } else {
      sidebar_top.style.top = (height_nav - (top - 2)) + 'px' ;
    } 
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#f2f2f2;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav{
     background: #222222;
     padding:10px 40px 10px 70px;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     border-left: none;
     border-right: none;
     
     width: 100%;
}

.nav ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav ul li.logo{
    flex:1;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav ul div.items{
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.nav ul div.items a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18 px;
    padding:0 12px;
}

.nav ul div.items a:hover{
    color:cyan
}

.searchicon{
    height:40px;
    width:240px;
    display:flex;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.searchicon input{
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    border:none;
    padding:0 10px;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.searchicon .icon{
    height:100%;
    width:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1 px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.searchicon .icon:hover{
    background: red;
}

.searchicon .icon span{
    color:#222222;
    font-size: 18px;

}

.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left:-300px;
    width:300px;
    /*height:100%;*/
    height:100vh; /*add*/
    background:#042331;
    /*transition:all .5s ease;*/
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-property: left;
}

.sidebar header{
    font-size:22px;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    background:#063146;
    user-select: none;
}

.sidebar ul a{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    line-height:65px;
    font-size:20px ;
    color:white;
    padding-left: 33px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition:0.4s;
}


ul li:hover a{
    padding-left: 43px;

}

.sidebar ul a i{
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.sidebar ul .setting-btn.show{
    display:block;
}

.sidebar span{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    font-size:25px;
    margin-top:18px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#check{
    display:none;
}

label #btn, label #cancel{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#042331;
    border-radius:3px;
}

label #btn{
    left:10px;
    top:9px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color:white;
    padding:6px 12px;
    transition:all .5s;
}

label #cancel{
    z-index:1111;
    left:-195px;
    top:78px;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#0a5275;
    padding:4px 9px;
    transition:all .5s ease;
}

#check:checked ~ .sidebar{
    /*position: sticky;*/ /*add*/
    /*top: 0;*/ /*add*/
    left:0;
    /*position: fixed;*/

}

#check:checked ~ label #btn{
    left:250px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;

}

#check:checked ~ label #cancel{
    left:250px;
    

}

.parent-container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.container1{
    
    width:75%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #e3e4e6;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container1-items{
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px;
    font-size:25px;
    
}

.container1 .container1-items a{
    color:slategray;
    padding:5px;
}

.container1 .container1-items i{
    color:slategray;
}

.container2{
    
    width:75%;
    height:220px;
    margin:20px;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #FFF;
    
}

.container2-items{
    width:28%;
    height:60px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right: 34px;
    font-size:25px;
    border:1px solid black;
    color:black;
    
    
}

.container3{
    
    width:75%;
    height:450px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container3-header{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    padding:10px;
    display:flex;
}

.container3-header-link{
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#1BBAE1;
    
}



.container3-item1{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:48%;
    height:450px;
    margin-right:40px;
}

.container3-item2{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:48%;
    height:450px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.container3-item2-1{
    width:100%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
.container3-item2-1-1{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
}
.container3-item2-2{
    width:100%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
.container3-item2-2-1{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="logo">Hakuna-Mipaka</li>
            <div class="items">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <li class="searchicon">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
                <label class="icon">
                    <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                </label>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>

    </label>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <header>My Profile</header>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hamburger"></i>My Shop<span class="fas fa-angle-right"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="setting-btn"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Settings & privacy<span
                        class="fas fa-angle-right first"></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>Help & support<span
                        class="fas fa-angle-right"></span></a> </li>


            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment-alt"></i>Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hotel"></i>name</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>Address</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt"></i>Phone_number</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-building"></i>City</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-fax"></i>Pincode</a></div>

        </div>

        <div class="container2">
            <div class="container2-items">1</div>
            <div class="container2-items">2</div>
            <div class="container2-items">3</div>
            <div class="container2-items">4</div>
            <div class="container2-items">5</div>

        </div>

        <div class="container3">
            <div class="container3-item1">
                <div class="container3-header">
                    Your <strong>Events</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container3-item2">
                <div class="container3-item2-1">
                    <div class="container3-item2-1-1">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container3-item2-2">
                    <div class="container3-item2-2-1">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to run your code snippet, when i try to open sidebar, every content shifts downward, i want them at their place.

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj, I redid it as you need it. Wrote a little jquery. Everything is working well now. Check this.

Comment: Pal try to scroll slowly, you will see that sidebar and the close button also moving upward, can you fix this pls.

Comment: I modified my jquery again + changed the animation in css so that there were no shifts when scrolling. Check it out.

Comment: later i am going to convert all of this in react.js and jquery doesnt work there, can you solvw this using html and css only??

Comment: Will you be happy with the option if I transfer to vanilla js? Js with react works.

Comment: Why did you uncheck the box to confirm the benefits of the answer? In your question, initially you did not indicate the need to do only for html and css, and did not say anything about the react. I have completed the task according to your question. You need to redo the code to vanilla js and this is already considered an ADDITIONAL REQUIREMENT. I will convert jquery to js, ​​but return the confirm checkbox. It will be fair.

Comment: I am waiting for the js version

Comment: Now I have a lot of work to do. I'm sorry. I'll do it tonight.

Comment: Check this solution

Answer (score 1):

You must set both x and y offset if you want an element `position` as `fixed`. You can fix it by adding `top: 0;` to `#check:checked ~ .sidebar`.

Example:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#f2f2f2;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav{
     background: #222222;
     padding:10px 40px 10px 70px;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     border-left: none;
     border-right: none;
     
     width: 100%;
}

.nav ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.nav ul li.logo{
    flex:1;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.nav ul div.items{
    padding: 0 25px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.nav ul div.items a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18 px;
    padding:0 12px;
}

.nav ul div.items a:hover{
    color:cyan
}

.searchicon{
    height:40px;
    width:240px;
    display:flex;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.searchicon input{
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    border:none;
    padding:0 10px;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.searchicon .icon{
    height:100%;
    width:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1 px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.searchicon .icon:hover{
    background: red;
}

.searchicon .icon span{
    color:#222222;
    font-size: 18px;

}

.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left:-300px;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background:#042331;
    transition:all .5s ease;
}

.sidebar header{
    font-size:22px;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    background:#063146;
    user-select: none;
}

.sidebar ul a{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    line-height:65px;
    font-size:20px ;
    color:white;
    padding-left: 33px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    transition:0.4s;
}


ul li:hover a{
    padding-left: 43px;

}

.sidebar ul a i{
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.sidebar ul .setting-btn.show{
    display:block;
}

.sidebar span{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    font-size:25px;
    margin-top:18px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#check{
    display:none;
}

label #btn, label #cancel{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#042331;
    border-radius:3px;
}

label #btn{
    left:10px;
    top:9px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color:white;
    padding:6px 12px;
    transition:all .5s;
}

label #cancel{
    z-index:1111;
    left:-195px;
    top:78px;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#0a5275;
    padding:4px 9px;
    transition:all .5s ease;
}

#check:checked ~ .sidebar{
    left:0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

#check:checked ~ label #btn{
    left:250px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;

}

#check:checked ~ label #cancel{
    left:250px;
    

}

.parent-container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.container1{
    
    width:75%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #e3e4e6;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container1-items{
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px;
    font-size:25px;
    
}

.container1 .container1-items a{
    color:slategray;
    padding:5px;
}

.container1 .container1-items i{
    color:slategray;
}

.container2{
    
    width:75%;
    height:220px;
    margin:20px;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #FFF;
    
}

.container2-items{
    width:28%;
    height:60px;
    padding:15px;
    margin-right: 34px;
    font-size:25px;
    border:1px solid black;
    color:black;
    
    
}

.container3{
    
    width:75%;
    height:450px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:20px;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container3-header{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    padding:10px;
    display:flex;
}

.container3-header-link{
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#1BBAE1;
    
}



.container3-item1{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:48%;
    height:450px;
    margin-right:40px;
}

.container3-item2{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:48%;
    height:450px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.container3-item2-1{
    width:100%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
.container3-item2-1-1{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
}
.container3-item2-2{
    width:100%;
    height:220px;
    border:1px solid black;

}
.container3-item2-2-1{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #394263;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="logo">Hakuna-Mipaka</li>
            <div class="items">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
            <li class="searchicon">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
                <label class="icon">
                    <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                </label>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>

    </label>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <header>My Profile</header>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-hamburger"></i>My Shop<span class="fas fa-angle-right"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="setting-btn"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Settings & privacy<span
                        class="fas fa-angle-right first"></span></a></li>

            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>Help & support<span
                        class="fas fa-angle-right"></span></a> </li>


            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment-alt"></i>Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hotel"></i>name</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>Address</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt"></i>Phone_number</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-building"></i>City</a></div>
            <div class="container1-items"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-fax"></i>Pincode</a></div>

        </div>

        <div class="container2">
            <div class="container2-items">1</div>
            <div class="container2-items">2</div>
            <div class="container2-items">3</div>
            <div class="container2-items">4</div>
            <div class="container2-items">5</div>

        </div>

        <div class="container3">
            <div class="container3-item1">
                <div class="container3-header">
                    Your <strong>Events</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container3-item2">
                <div class="container3-item2-1">
                    <div class="container3-item2-1-1">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container3-item2-2">
                    <div class="container3-item2-2-1">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hello there is an issue, when i open sidebar, it covers the logo, i want it to be opened below the logo,and when i scroll down the close button moves towards top, try to run your code snippet, you will get the problem,pal.